# Error: Couldn't find a navigation context. Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'?

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-navigation, react-native-web, react-flow

I'm getting this error on every render. The stack trace below started with a mouse §click.  The problem is I have no clue how to approach this. What I gather from this trace is:

- It seems to happen inside React
- Apparently it happens while React is reconciling the virtual DOM and the real DOM?
- Somehow React Navigation has hooked into this process and is complaining.

And here it ends for me.

What am I using:

- Expo Go SDK 46
- React Native Web 0.18.7
- Reactflow 11.2.0

So how do I go about debugging this? BTW I *did* wrap everything in a navigation container.

[image]

```
console.<computed>                 @    index.js:1
error                              @    react-native-logs.fx.ts:34
overrideMethod                     @    react_devtools_backend.js:4026
i                                  @    VM8448:10
t.onCommitFiberRoot.t.onCommitFiberRoot @   VM8448:10
onCommitRoot                       @    react-dom.development.js:4875
commitRootImpl                     @    react-dom.development.js:26709
commitRoot                         @    react-dom.development.js:26517
performSyncWorkOnRoot              @    react-dom.development.js:25956
flushSyncCallbacks                 @    react-dom.development.js:11982
flushSyncCallbacksOnlyInLegacyMode @    react-dom.development.js:11961
scheduleUpdateOnFiber              @    react-dom.development.js:25326
dispatchReducerAction              @    react-dom.development.js:17269
listener                           @    index.js:138
(anonymous)                        @    index.js:18
setState                           @    index.js:17
(anonymous)                        @    index.ts:21
setNodes                           @    slice.ts:120
(anonymous)                        @    SlideEditorCanvas.tsx:139
(anonymous)                        @    index.js:2308
call                               @    dispatch.js:57
emit                               @    zoom.js:219
start                              @    zoom.js:198
mousedowned                        @    zoom.js:283
(anonymous)                        @    on.js:3
```

Comment: My question might be silly, but Have you wrapped your app with 'NavigationContainer'? You haven't provided any of the code, so we need to start from something

Comment: Should've mentioned that. Yes I did, that has been in for a year now. I was hoping someone would glance at the stacktrace and would say: 'you - or react flow - probably have forgot to bind a function to this, try the following to track it down'. Or something along those lines.

Comment: From the stack trace it looks like you have a part of the app that is not wrapped in NavigationContainer and is trying to use navigation context (probably navigation hook)